# Django - how to order queryset for varying query?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have this issue where I want to order my queryset according to a compute value based on a query in descending order.

Query: ?fruit=Apple&?fruit=Pear

In this case:
Num. Apples + Num. Pears + (Num. Apples * Num. Pears)

models.py

```
class Costumer(BaseModel):
        name = models.CharField('name'), max_length=255, blank=True
        fruits = models.JsonField('fruit'), null=True, blank=True, default=dict)
```

My Costumer.fruits looks something like this:

`fruits = {name: Apple, count: 10}, {name: Pear, count:4}, {name: Cherry, count: 1}, {name: Avocado, count: 2}`

views.py

```
def get_queryset(self):
        fruits = dict(self.request.GET).get('fruit', [])
        queryset = Costumers.objects.all()
        if fruits:
               queryset = sorted(queryset, reverse = True, key=lambda costumer: self.calculate_order(costumer, fruits))
        return queryset

def calculate_order(self, costumer, fruits):
        value_list = [fruit['count'] for fruit in costumer.fruits if fruit['name'] in fruits]
        return sum(value_list) + (reduce((lambda x, y: x*y), value_list)) if value_list else 0
```

This seems to be ordering the data correctly from what I have tested so far, however doesn't seem like the best way to do it.
Is there a better way using Django Queryset API for ordering this data? Since the way it's ordering now is a bit time consuming since I have to iterate on all the records on the database.

Edit:
I have no problem with having another model for fruits.

```
class Costumer(BaseModel): 
        name = models.CharField('name'),  max_length=255, blank=True
        fruits = models.ManytoManyField(Fruits, through='CostumerFruits')

class Fruits(BaseModel): 
        name = models.CharField('name'), max_length=255, blank=True 
        count = models.IntegerField('count'), null=True, blank=True
```

How can I order the Costumer information using this two models with the computed value?

Comment: Please don't use a `JsonField` in case the modeling is a many-to-many relation. It makes querying harder, and less effective to guarantee structural (and referential) integrity.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I edited the question, I have no problem with having two models...